# Swift: Casting [UInt32] to AnyObject

Tags: iphone, swift, downcast

I have a `UInt32` array of `Int`s defined as: `var myArr : [UInt32] = [1, 2, 3]` how can I convert it to `AnyObject` type ?  I've tried the forced downcast `as! AnyObject` but the compiler gives this warning: `treating a forced downcast to AnyObject as optional will never produce nil`

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why you need to recast it.

Comment: it's a requirement in my project

Comment: i wonder why should this question be closed and why down voting it ? is there something wrong in the question ?

Comment: [It's an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You should have shown what you were originally trying to do in the question, instead of mentioning it after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

A UInt32 is not like an Int. You cannot cast a UInt32 to an AnyObject, as they are not bridged. You will have to wrap every UInt32 in the array in an NSNumber explicitly, using `map`.

Comment: that would be very slow for a huge bytes array of [UInt32]

Comment: Maybe, but you are the one who wants to cast this thing, not me. And the same would be true of an array of Int except that the mapping is performed for you automatically.

Comment: [Int] is bridged with AnyObject, i.e. if you assign [Int] to myDict["myArr"] where myDict is defined as myDict = [String: AnyObject]() then the compiler will not complain